Incorrect [Graduate] badge awarded with single published Staging Ground post
Today, I got a notification about receiving the Graduate badge:

This badge is supposed to be awarded to users who asked two questions in the Staging Ground that are then published.
And while I did ask two questions during the beta tests (we were given a way to directly ask questions in the Staging Ground during the betas), only one of them was published (the badge award date matches the publication date of the question). My other Staging Ground post was deleted by myself.
When looking at other users who were awarded this badge, I can see users who got that badge with only a single Staging Ground question (I can't search for deleted posts of specific users though).
Please either edit the badge text or make sure this badge is only awarded to users who should get it.

Can confirm that user does not have any deleted SG posts

So, you dropped out before graduating?!!

@M-- I mean, SO still gives me the certificate so...

We decided to lower the threshold for the graduate badge to one successful question rather than two. We don't want to delay new askers access to getting their questions answered, by keeping them in the Staging Ground, once they have shown that they can ask a question thats appropriate for the site. We are still working on scaling Staging Ground to meet the need of new askers, including minimizing the time it takes for their questions to get reviewed and published to the main site. This change is one way to make sure these delays are not prohibitive to users engaging on Stack Overflow.

Thank you for updating the badge description to match how it's being awarded. "Ask one question successfully on the main site from Staging Ground." is definitely a better notification for this badge since it'll be awarded after a single published post. I wonder if this question should be tagged status-completed rather than bydesign since this change to the notification and description text was made after this request to "either edit the badge text or make sure this badge is only awarded to users who should get it."
